# NodeJS Express Route not working with form action

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a form that should be submitting data so node js can process it. I followed exact examples but for some reason keep getting the following error when submitting the  form: 404: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'c:\path\submit'

Not sure where I am going wrong here, but I have app.js running in the background and when submitting the form it never makes it over to the app.post('/submit')

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
var snowflake = require('snowflake-sdk');

const port = 3335;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
   

//Receive data from form submission
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
let country, state, city, language = "";
app.post('/submit', (req, res) => {
    country = res.req.body.country;
    state = res.req.body.state;
    city = res.req.body.city;
    language = res.req.body.language;
    console.log(`'${country}','${state}','${city}','${language}'`)
    
    res.redirect("http://localhost:52330/success.html")
});
```

And here is my html form:

```
        <form action="/submit" method="POST">
            <div class="banner">
            </div>
            
            <div class="position-item">
                <div class="item">
                    <p>What country are you from?</p>
                    <select name="country" required>
                        <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
                        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="position-item">
                <div class="item">
                    <p>What state/province are you from?</p>
                    <select name="state" required>
                        <option value="Ontario">Ontario</option>
                        <option value="New York">New York</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="position-item">
                <div class="item">
                    <p>What town/city are you from?</p>
                    <select name="city" required>
                        <option value="Toronto">Toronto</option>
                        <option value="Mexico City">Mexico City</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="position-item">
                <div class="item">
                    <p>What is your native language?</p>
                    <select name="language" required>
                        <option value="English">English</option>
                        <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="btn-block">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Forms are not urlencoded by default (indeed I don't know if you can force a form to send as urlencoded) instead forms are sent as form-data

Comment: @slebetman — Forms **are** urlencoded by default. You need to set the `enctype` attribute to change it to multipart/form-data.

Comment: Move the `app.listen()` command down to the end of your script. Order is important; you were starting your server without setting up anything first.

Comment: Looks like the html file is not served from node js server. Serve the html file at a route in the express server.

Comment: @ChrisG I have changed the order, but am still receiving the 404 error.

Comment: Ok wait, how are you looking at the form? Are you going to http://localhost:3335? Because if your app doesn't serve that HTML doc, you need to change the `action` to `http://localhost:3335/submit`. A relative path like `/submit` will only work if your express app is serving the form, and I don't see `app.get("/", ...)` anywhere.

Comment: add express static serving and put your HTML file in that directory